# Process ID of an AppDomain

Tags: c#

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id
```

gives us the "AppDomain" process id of the current app domain, but what I'd like to know is the windows process id of the container process that contains this AppDomain.  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All AppDomains in your application live inside the same windows process - that is, your app's process. So you just need:

```
int nProcessID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
```

Answer (score 2):

All AppDomains belong to a single process. You can retrieve this from a System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id